# Change directory to where a slurm script is running

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am trying to directly change directory (`cd`) to the folder where a job is running with SLURM workload manager.

I can check where a SLURM script is running with

```
squeue --format %Z% -j 123
```

Now I can also extract, the directory name as

```
echo   $(squeue --format "%Z" -j <jobid>) | awk '{print $2}'
```

**(Edit on 26 November 2021.)**
It does show the folder name in the terminal, say

```
/HDD_Drive/myfiles/myfolder
```

But when I use `cd` in conjunction with this, I am still in the current folder. Interestingly, if I check a process PID the same way:

```
cd "$(pwdx <PID> | awk '{print $2}')"
```

It does change my directory but when checking the SLURM job id, I have this strange behavior. In summary:

```
echo $(squeue --format "%Z" -j jobid ) | awk '{print $2}'
```

shows the current directory as

```
/HDD_Drive/myfiles/myfolder
```

but

```
cd $(squeue --format "%Z" -j 212 ) | awk '{print $2}'
```

shows

```
-bash: cd: too many arguments
```

and with

```
cd $(squeue --format "%Z" -j 212 | awk '{print $2}')
```

I am still in the current directory. Thank you!

Comment: I think you almost made it, but it would _really_ be helpful if you included (possibly anonymized) example output of all commands you specify.

Comment: Question: You showed was `echo $(squeue --format "%Z" -j  jobid) | awk '{print $2}'` outputs. Can you post what directly executing `squeue --format "%Z" -j jobid | awk '{print $2}'` gives as output? There must be some subtle difference to explain the behavior. Note that the result of `cd $(squeue --format "%Z" -j 212 ) | awk '{print $2}'
` is absolutely logical, because that would try to `cd` to the output of `squeue --format "%Z" -j 212` (which contains several fields), and pipe the output of the `cd` operation (which is empty; the error goes to `stderr`) to `awk`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I will accept your as the working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost made it since you were able to extract the directory. Now, you just need to use this as argument to `cd`:

```
cd $(squeue --format "%Z" | awk '{print $2}')
```

should do. The command substitution `$( ... )` will be replaced by the output of the commands in the parentheses.

Note that this means the syntax you used in your attempt is unnecessarily convoluted: Since `$( cmd )` is being replaced with the *output* of the command in the parentheses, `echo $( cmd )` does the same as simply calling `cmd`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it do not change the directory. I mean after using  `cd $(squeue --format "%Z" -j <jodid> | awk '{print $2}')` or  `cd $(squeue --format "%Z" | awk '{print $2}')', I am still in the home directory.